# Which design pattern should I use for a TODO list in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, oop

Which design pattern should I use for a very simple Object-oriented todo list?

Initially I started off with classes for Task, TaskList, Driver. Also a simple UI displaying a list of the Task titles. I was struggling to have the UI update the list when new tasks were added, and in trying to solve this I realised my whole layout was probably wrong.

I'm looking for someone to give me a basic direction, or perhaps a link to a design pattern diagram with a little guidance on how my classes relate to the diagram.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general architecture should implement the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern (or Model-View-Presenter with a stronger decoupling of model and view) , and it looks, like you started with that already. You have classes, that represent 'the task' and 'the tasklist' and you have an UI to present the tasklist (the model) to the user. Now you need an interface (or a set of interfaces) for the model and the ui and you want to make sure, that the model does not know the ui and the ui does not know the model.

Because in between, you have the presenter class(es), that will react on model changes and ui events (Observer pattern, databinding as a technique). It can listen to the model and update the view. So you want to make your model observable. And it can listen to events from the view (value edits, actions) and pass this information to the model, so it can (try to) adapt to the user intended changes (the model and only the model will validate the user input and give a response to the presenter).

Yes, it is quite complex. To start off, break your application into the three parts (model, view, controller/presenter) and make the model observable. So you can start easily with a view that is automatically update when the model changes. And then, step by step, you could add functionality to react on user inputs on the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Another piece of advice: Assuming you're writing your UI in Swing, **do not** use `DefaultTableModel` and copy `Task`s from your `TaskList` into the model (i.e. do not hold your data in two places).  Instead, subclass `AbstractTableModel` and have it act as a thin wrapper around the `TaskList`; e.g.

```
public class TaskTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  private final TaskList taskList;  

  public TaskTableModel(TaskList taskList) {
    this.taskList = taskList;
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    Task task = taskList.getTask(row);
    Object ret;

    switch(column) {
      case 0:
        ret = task.getStartTime();
        break;
      case 1:
        ret = task.getState();
        break;
        // etc ...
    }

    return ret;
  }

  // TODO: Implement other TableModel methods.
}
```

Comment: Currently my Tasklist class stores an ArrayList of type 'Task' objects. Do you think doing it in a table would be preferable?

Comment: It's the approach I usually take with this type of problem, where each row in table corresponds to a business object and each column is one of the business object's attributes.  I'd stay away from JList; the API sucks and you can always mimic it with a single column JTable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the observer pattern - but take a look at this previous stack overflow question [Should I use a Listener or Observer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744762/should-i-use-a-listener-or-observer)

Comment: Hi jskaggz, that will be useful for the UI part, however I was hoping for some guidance on the overall approach to the solution.

Comment: My fault, I thought you were asking to be pointed to the correct pattern.  :-P  Cutting to the chase, if you're using java, get glazed lists (http://www.glazedlists.com/)  which implements the observer pattern

Answer (score 1):

The Model-View-Controller (MVC). Basically, the Model stores the task, the Controller handles the events and the View the display. You can have several view, i.e. one to display the tasks in the UI, and one to save to disk.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to understand your design without some code or diagram but i will give it a shot

Depends upon your particular situation is it list being update in **back-end**(Database/controller) and reflected in **front-end**(View-html5,angularJs) or vice-versa or it can happen in either of the places **or** where you want to apply the fix(front-end/Back-end) consider all interactions while applying the fix.

In front-end probable approaches

1. Ajax (data flows back and forth from front-end to back-end)
2. Angular js use can use promise or the simple $http, or something as simple as ng-repeate.
3. HTML5 - have something as dynamic dataListControl

In back-end probable approaches

1. Observer pattern
2. Whole architecture you can go as far as a event-driven-architecture https://martinfowler.com/articles/201701-event-driven.html 
   as you felt your deign was wrong from the scratch.

As your were looking for the basic direction this might help

1. https://martinfowler.com/aboutMe.html
2. Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch
3. Head First Books

**2 cents - use some frameworks they makes life easier if you are starting the design journey.**

Use frameworks let's say SPRING forces you to use many patterns without you even knowing them such as MVC,Front Controller,AOP,Singleton(beans),Template(JDBC,JpaTemplate) etc.

Happy Designing till then :)

Comment: Hi Arvind. Ignoring that I asked this in 2009!
You've answered the question completely confusing Java, which the question is about, and JavaScript, which couldn't be more different! And why you've included a link to Martin Fowlers about me page I don't know.